# Como bloquear uma range de IPs com php?

Tags: php, ip

Tenho uma função no php, mas não gostaria que ela fosse executada por pessoas de um certo país, como faço para que o script php bloqueie uma range de IPs?

Exemplo, bloquear a range de IPs dos EUA.

É necessário que seja possível adicionar mais range de IPs.

Comment: Teria algum motivo específico para não bloquear usando o próprio `nginx` ou `apache`? Eles tendem a ser muito mais eficientes para essa atividade.

Comment: Sim, o bloqueio dinâmico @Inkeliz

Comment: Você pode usar o GeoIP para isso, http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php. Essa função está "obsoleta", porque não suporta o IPv6 nativamente. Ele retorna os países em ISO 3166 como pode ver em http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/. Então basta comparar a geolocalização do IP do usuário com o que deseja. Basta lembrar que isso NÃO é 100% preciso!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer de várias maneiras:

Supondo que queira bloquear a faixa: 90.25.*.*

1) Usando [**strpos**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "90.25") === 0)){ // se ip começa com 90.25
    echo 'bloqueado';
    exit;
}
```

2) Usando [**ip2long**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ip2long.php) com máscara no padrão: 255.255.0.0

```
$rede = ip2long("90.25.0.0");
$mascara = ip2long("255.255.0.0");
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if (($mascara & $mascara) == ($ip & $mascara)) {
        echo 'bloqueado';
        exit;
}
```

3) Usando [**ip2long**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ip2long.php) com máscara no padrão: 255.255.0.0/16

```
$rede = ip2long("90.25.0.0");
$prefixo = 16;
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($rede >> (32 - $prefixo )) == ($ip >> (32 - $prefixo )) {
     echo 'bloqueado';
     exit;
}
```

Para bloquear várias faixas, crie um `array` das faixas a serem bloqueadas e faça um `loop` repetindo o bloqueio.

Nota: Baseada nas respostas à [pergunta de iTayb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2869893/4921014)