# Como bloquear site e deixar livre apenas para alguns ips?

Tags: php, ip

Gostaria de sabe como posso bloquear meu site que está em manutenção e deixar livre acesso para para dois ips, estou fazendo desse jeito , mas ele só deixa livre pra um. Quero que fique livre para os dois apenas .

```
$ip = '10.11.30.175';
$ip ='10.11.30.182';


if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $ip )
   die('Site em manutenção, voltaremos em instantes');
```

Comment: joga esses dois ip's em um array e usa a função in_array  pra ver se REMOTE_ADDR combina com algum dos valores dele.

Comment: Pode comparar isso com um array (lembre de usa a função `in_array()` ou `or`. Primeiro sua variável deve ser um array ;).

Comment: @rray pode por isso como resposta da pergunta , pois tentei fazer do jeito que falou e não aparece nada na tela .

Comment: No seu exemplo vc está sobrescrevendo o valor da variável `$ip`

Comment: Veja minha resposta sobre esta pergunta em: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/150386/31016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar a função `in_array()` para verificar quais ips tem acesso ao site.

```
$validos = array('10.11.30.175', '10.11.30.182');
if (! in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $validos)) die('Site em manutenção, voltaremos em instantes');
```

Comment: só uma pergunta só os dois ips irão ver o site né . Pois tá aparecendo o site . Obrigado .

Comment: @allanaraujo era isso?

Comment: isso , tá liberado o site apenas para o dois ips .

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo seu raciocínio :

```
$ip1 = '10.11.30.175';
$ip2 ='10.11.30.182';


if ( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $ip1 || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $ip2 )
   die('Site em manutenção, voltaremos em instantes');
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção para bloquear os acessos seria via `.htaccess`:

**APACHE 2.4**

```
<Limit GET POST>
 Require all denied
 Require ip 10.11.30.175
 Require ip 10.11.30.182
</Limit>
```

**APACHE 2.2**

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 10.11.30.175
 allow from 10.11.30.182
</Limit>
```

Answer (score 2):

seu script deveria ser assim

primeiro parte ( função de validação )

```
function valida($ip){
   $retorna=false;
   $liberado=array('10.11.30.175','10.11.30.182');
   for($i=0;$i<count($liberado);$i++){
      if($ip==$liberado[$i]){ $retorna=true; }
   }
   return $retorna;
}
```

este cod cima pode ser um include externo ou em qualquer lugar da sua pagina php
para usar basta fazer o seguinte

```
if (!valida($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) die('Site em manutenção, voltaremos em instantes');
```

se quiser adicionar mais ips basta incluir no array da variavel liberado mais ips separados por , dentro de aspas simples.

Comment: esse código fica da mesma forma tudo em branco .

Comment: errei no i++ mudei para $i++

Comment: testei no http://phptester.net/ e rolo d boa